# How to make the function work for the private chat window in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, chat

I have a form window called channel from where user will login and get connected to neptune.smokeynet.org server.And its working fine.
After user logged in It will show the online users on the right side of the form.

So I am able to type message and sent in public window its working fine for public view but when I click on the online users and type message to sent him I get an error 
**"NullReferenceException was unhandled"
Object reference not set to an instance of an object** in this form named as

This form is responsible for private chat with online users. How to make a user sent message to online users as soon as he logs in successfully.
 **privatechat.vb**

```
Public Class privatechat
   Public irc As New channel
   Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles prvmsgtxt.Click
        If prvmsg.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter a Message", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Enter Messages")
        Else
            irc.irc.SendRAW("PRIVMSG" & Space(1) & pvtlabel.Text & Space(1) & prvmsg.Text)
            prvtextbox.AppendText("<" & irc.irc.Nick & "> " & prvmsg.Text & vbNewLine)
            prvmsg.Clear()
            prvmsg.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles prvtextbox.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub prvmsg_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles prvmsg.TextChanged

    End Sub
    Private Sub private_messageincome(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles prvtextbox.TextChanged

    End Sub
    Private Sub pvtlabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pvtlabel.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub prvnametxt_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    End Sub

    Public Sub privatechat_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        BackColor = login.BackColor
        ForeColor = login.ForeColor

    End Sub
End Class
```

Another main form for connection which is working fine 
**Channel.vb**

```
    Imports TechLifeForum

Public Class channel
    Public WithEvents irc As IrcClient
    Public txtnick As String
    Dim chatfrm(100) As privatechat
    Dim z As Integer = 1

    Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        irc.Connect()
    End Sub

    Public Sub channel_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        irc = New IrcClient("neptune.smokeynet.org", 6667)
        irc.Nick = login.txtnick.Text
        lstUsers.Enabled = False
        txtSend.Enabled = False
        btnSend.Enabled = False
        irc.Connect()
        rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Brown
        rtbOutput.AppendText("* * * Attempting to connect to the chat server * * * " & vbNewLine)
        Connectbtn.Enabled = False
        BackColor = login.BackColor
        ForeColor = login.ForeColor

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        If txtSend.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter a Message")

        Else
            irc.Nick = login.txtnick.Text
            'irc.SendRAW("PRIVMSG #nepal " & txtSend.Text)
            irc.SendMessage("#nepal", txtSend.Text)
            rtbOutput.AppendText("<" & irc.Nick & "> " & txtSend.Text & vbNewLine)
            txtSend.Clear()
            txtSend.Focus()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSend_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSend.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            btnSend.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub irc_ChannelMessage(Channel As String, User As String, Message As String) Handles irc.ChannelMessage
        rtbOutput.AppendText("<" & User & "> " & Message & vbNewLine)
        rtbOutput.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
    Private Sub irc_userjoin(channel As String, User As String) Handles irc.UserJoined
        rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Green
        rtbOutput.AppendText("*** " & User & " has joined the chatroom" & vbNewLine)


    End Sub
    Private Sub irc_userleft(channel As String, User As String) Handles irc.UserLeft
        rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        rtbOutput.AppendText("*** " & User & " has left the chatroom" & vbNewLine)

    End Sub
    Sub UserNickChangeEventDelegate(oldUser As String, newUser As String) Handles irc.UserNickChange

        rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
        rtbOutput.AppendText("*** " & oldUser & " is now knows as " & newUser & vbNewLine)
        lstUsers.Update()

    End Sub


    Private Sub irc_PrivateMessage(User As String, message As String) Handles irc.PrivateMessage


        Dim t As Integer = 1
        Dim found As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 1

        If z = 1 Then
            For i = 1 To 100
                chatfrm(i) = New privatechat
            Next
            z += 1
        End If

        For i = 1 To 100
            If Trim(chatfrm(i).pvtlabel.Text) = User Then
                found = 1
                t = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If found = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To 100
                If chatfrm(i).pvtlabel.Text = " " Then
                    t = i
                    chatfrm(t).Show()
                    chatfrm(t).Focus()
                    chatfrm(t).pvtlabel.Text = User
                    chatfrm(t).prvtextbox.AppendText("<" & User & ">" & message & vbNewLine)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        ElseIf found = 1 Then

            chatfrm(t).prvtextbox.AppendText("<" & User & ">" & message & vbNewLine)
            chatfrm(t).Show()
            chatfrm(t).Focus()
        End If


    End Sub
    Private Sub irc_ExceptionThrown(ex As System.Exception) Handles irc.ExceptionThrown
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub irc_OnConnect() Handles irc.OnConnect
        irc.SendRAW("mode" & Space(1) & irc.Nick & Space(1) & "-B")
        If login.txtpass.Text = "" Then
        Else
            irc.SendRAW("PRIVMSG nickserv identify" & Space(1) & login.txtpass.Text)
        End If
        lstUsers.Enabled = True
        irc.JoinChannel("#nepal")
        btnSend.Enabled = True
        txtSend.Enabled = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub irc_ServerMessage(message As String) Handles irc.ServerMessage
        'rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Brown
        'rtbOutput.AppendText(message & vbNewLine)
    End Sub
    Public Sub irc_noticemessage(User As String, message As String) Handles irc.NoticeMessage
        If User = "NickServ" And message = "Password incorrect." Then
            password.Show()
        Else
        End If
        If login.txtpass.Text = "" And User = "NickServ" And message = "please choose a different nick." Then
            password.Show()
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub irc_UpdateUsers(Channel As String, userlist() As String) Handles irc.UpdateUsers
        lstUsers.Items.Clear()
        lstUsers.Items.AddRange(userlist)
        totaluser.Text = "Total Users: " & lstUsers.Items.Count
    End Sub

    Private Sub rtbOutput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rtbOutput.TextChanged


    End Sub
    Public Sub nickttaken(Nick As String) Handles irc.NickTaken
        changenick.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lstUsers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstUsers.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub
    Private Sub lstUsers_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstUsers.MouseDoubleClick
        Dim tmpnick, flet As String
        tmpnick = lstUsers.SelectedItem
        flet = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(lstUsers.SelectedItem, 1)
        If Trim(flet) = "@" Or Trim(flet) = "%" Or Trim(flet) = "+" Or Trim(flet) = "~" Or Trim(flet) = "&" Then
            tmpnick = Mid(tmpnick, 2, Len(tmpnick) - 1)
        End If



        Dim t As Integer = 1
        Dim found As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 1

        If z = 1 Then
            For i = 1 To 100
                chatfrm(i) = New privatechat
            Next
            z += 1
        End If

        For i = 1 To 100
            If Trim(chatfrm(i).pvtlabel.Text) = tmpnick Then
                found = 1
                t = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If found = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To 100
                If chatfrm(i).pvtlabel.Text = " " Then
                    t = i
                    chatfrm(t).Show()
                    chatfrm(t).Focus()
                    chatfrm(t).pvtlabel.Text = tmpnick

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        ElseIf found = 1 Then
            chatfrm(t).Show()
            chatfrm(t).Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub lstUsers_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lstUsers.MouseUp

    End Sub
    Private Sub menuChoice(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim item = CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
        Dim selection = CInt(item.Tag)
        '-- etc
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ConnectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Connectbtn.Click
        irc = New IrcClient("127.0.0.1", 6667)
        rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Brown
        rtbOutput.AppendText("* * * Attempting to connect to the chat server * * * " & vbNewLine)
        irc.Nick = login.txtnick.Text
        irc.Connect()
        If irc.Connected = True Then
            Disconnectbtn.Enabled = True
        Else
            Disconnectbtn.Enabled = True
            Connectbtn.Enabled = False
        End If
        rtbOutput.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub FIleToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FileToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        irc.Disconnect()
        rtbOutput.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtSend_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSend.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub DisconnectToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Disconnectbtn.Click
        If irc.Connected = True Then
            Disconnectbtn.Enabled = False
            Connectbtn.Enabled = True
        Else
            Disconnectbtn.Enabled = True
            Connectbtn.Enabled = False

        End If
        If irc.Connected = True Then
            rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            irc.SendRAW("quit Using SmokeyNet Messenger Beta Version 1.0")
        Else

        End If
        lstUsers.Items.Clear()
        rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Purple
        rtbOutput.AppendText("* * * Disconnected * * * " & vbNewLine)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim exitmsn As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        exitmsn = MsgBox("Do you really want to Quit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Exit Messenger")
        If exitmsn = MsgBoxResult.Yes And irc.Connected = True Then
            rtbOutput.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            irc.SendRAW("quit Using SmokeyNet Messenger Beta Version 1.0")
            End
        Else
            End
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub rtbOutput_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rtbOutput.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub AboutMessengerToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutMessengerToolStripMenuItem.Click
        About.Show()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    End Sub



    Private Sub ClearChatTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearChatTextToolStripMenuItem.Click
        rtbOutput.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RefreshToolStripMenuItem.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeNicknameToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeNicknameToolStripMenuItem.Click
        changenick.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MenuStrip1_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles MenuStrip1.ItemClicked

    End Sub

    Private Sub EnterPasswordToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterPasswordToolStripMenuItem.Click
        password.Show()
    End Sub
    Public Sub NickTakenEventDelegate(nick As String)
        changenick.Show()

    End Sub
    Private Sub RegisterNickNameToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegisterNickNameToolStripMenuItem.Click
        registernick.Show()

    End Sub
    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles totaluser.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSend_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.DoubleClick
    End Sub

    Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub LightBlueToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LightBlueToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    End Sub

    Private Sub CornFlowerBlueToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CornFlowerBlueToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
    End Sub

    Private Sub HotPinkToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HotPinkToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.HotPink
    End Sub

    Private Sub BlackToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BlackToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.Black
        ForeColor = Color.Black
    End Sub

    Private Sub AliceBlueToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AliceBlueToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
    End Sub

    Private Sub MediumPurpleToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MediumPurpleToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.MediumPurple
    End Sub

    Private Sub FloralWhiteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FloralWhiteToolStripMenuItem.Click
        BackColor = Color.FloralWhite
    End Sub

    Private Sub WhoisToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WhoisToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim tmpnick, flet As String
        tmpnick = lstUsers.SelectedItem
        flet = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(lstUsers.SelectedItem, 1)
        If Trim(flet) = "@" Or Trim(flet) = "%" Or Trim(flet) = "+" Or Trim(flet) = "~" Or Trim(flet) = "&" Then
            tmpnick = Mid(tmpnick, 2, Len(tmpnick) - 1)
        End If
        irc.SendRAW("WHOIS" & Space(1) & tmpnick)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you might at least tell us where in that wall of code the error happens

Comment: its a line number 7 in the privatechat.vb

Comment: irc.Connect() this connects to a server now i need to be able to sent private message to online users